# Verbose routes in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm coming from a Rails background and I found my flask routes to become very messy very quickly. It seems like flask encourages you to put all of your controller logic into your route/app definition.

So instead of

```
resources :users
```

and throwing the implementation into users_controller.py

I get

```
@app.route("/users"), methods=["GET"]
def list_users():
    return ..

@app.route("/users/new"), methods=["GET"]
def new_user():
    return render_template("new")

@app.route("/users"), methods=["POST"]
def create_user()
    ....
```

Then add in another 4 actions. Is this really required?

I have tried with blueprints which seems to compare with Rails Engines, but it's not the kind of partitioning I'm looking for. How can I make my routes about my routes and not about their implementation? Do I really have to upgrade to Django?

#### Edit

To put it a different, perhaps clearer way: I want the methods out of my `app.py` file. And I want a higher abstraction than `route()` for defining CRUD resources. Something like

```
app.resources("users", controller=UsersController)
```

or better yet, have Flask resolve the controller based on the resource name.

The UsersController will then look something like this

```
class UsersController:

    def index():
        pass

    def show(user_id):
        pass

    def new():
        pass

    def create():
        pass

    def edit(user_id):
        pass

    def update():
        pass

    def delete():
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this perhaps? flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/views covers pluggable views, check the last part on [extending `MethodView`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/views/#method-views-for-apis).

```
class UserAPI(MethodView):

    def get(self, user_id):
        if user_id is None:
            # return a list of users
            pass
        else:
            # expose a single user
            pass

    def post(self):
        # create a new user
        pass

    def delete(self, user_id):
        # delete a single user
        pass

    def put(self, user_id):
        # update a single user
        pass
```

Just note that implementations of CRUD views don't come outside of the box in Flask, as per its design it tries to be unopinionated and flexible.